# differentiation of textures in the pictures

Tags: image, algorithm, textures

I would like to perform an algorithm, that would separate brown homogeneous from no homogeneous regions.

Which algorithm would be suitable for that task.

How picture look like:

[image]

I am currently working in Octave.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post an image showing the expected result for this input?

Comment: [Input -> Output](http://s27.postimg.org/gjps62g2b/image.jpg)

Comment: So are there 3 classes? (showing as red, green and gray in the output image)

Comment: Yes, but bright one is easy to separate.

Comment: one standard approach will be to use Gabor filter bank and than apply classification on the filter response.

Comment: you are looking for image segmentation. there are very many algorithms from edge detection usage to histogram comparison. I would divide image to small squares 16x16 pixel for example compute its properties and then joun similar neighbours which will lead to separation of object on your image. the property can be average color/intensity, histogram, DFT or FFT spectra, color/intensity deviation, ... and their combinations

Comment: I can't use edge detection because dark brown objects are not flat (even though it looks like). Thanks